# Drop duplicates in MultiIndexed pandas DataFrame by second index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a MultiIndexed DataFrame:

```
arrays = [
    np.array(["foo", "foo", "foo", "bar", "bar", "bar", "bar", "bar"]),
    np.array(["one", "two", "three", "four", "one", "two", "five", "six"]),
]

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 2), index=arrays)
```

which gives

```
                  0         1
foo one    0.320046 -0.423325
    two   -1.621356 -0.487854
    three  0.364116  0.385614
bar four   0.436584 -0.042120
    one    0.404953  0.410876
    two    1.695568 -1.475434
    five  -0.696704  1.226981
    six    1.640631  0.518874
```

I would like to drop the rows where the second index is duplicated, and keep the last instance (i.e., drop the rows with `("foo", "one")` and `("foo", "two")` in this example). I have attempted using `.drop_duplicates()`, but this will only drop rows with all elements identical. I've attempted to impose a `subset` argument in `.drop_duplicates()`, but have not been successful.

Comment: `df.groupby(level=1).tail()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `get_level_values`:

```
>>> df[~df.index.get_level_values(1).duplicated(keep="last")]
                  0         1
foo three -1.280063  0.457580
bar four  -0.558575  0.668510
    one   -0.552500 -0.526332
    two    1.777764  2.519594
    five   1.337699 -1.817843
    six   -1.362656  0.410239
```